# Azure Resource Manager - Get all the resources of a resource group

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net

Yesterday, I was using this line of code with the version 1.5.0-preview of Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager :

```
var listResources = 
ResourceManagementClient.ResourceGroups.ListResources(resourceGroup.Name);
```

Today, I have updated to version 1.6.0-preview but the fonction doesn't seem to be available anymore. Is there another way to get the list of the resources contained in a resource group ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now the SDK is still preview version. In the 1.6.0  preview version. It should use following code.

```
   var listResources = resourceManagementClient.Resources.ListByResourceGroup("ResourceGroup Name");
```

But it still can't work correctly on my side because the API-Version is **api-version=2017-05-10**. I catch the request with fiddler.

[image]

The code you mentioned that use API-version

```
var listResources = 
ResourceManagementClient.ResourceGroups.ListResources(resourceGroup.Name);
```

[image]

**Note** : Please still use  1.5.0-preview instead of 1.6.0-preview currently if you want get group resource, or give your feedback to azure sdk team . Or you can use REST API directly

Comment: Thanks but from where I can get `credentials` if I do not have access to Azure active directory ? any work around ?

Comment: @Neo Based on my knowledge, we need access to Azure active directory.